# Destiny: Weekly crucible bounties

Tags: ps4, destiny

I'm a Destiny veteran, but I just realized that I never completed crucible weekly bounties. I know that I have to go to lord Shax in the tower, but he doesn't give me the weekly bounty mission (as I saw on a video on youtube)...

How can I obtain crucible weekly bounties ?

Comment: Could you provide the Youtube video link in your post ?

Comment: I don't remember it, but it's not important, the point is that if you go to the lord Shax and interact with him, in the character screen you should be able to pickup the weekly crucible bounty... which is a red box at the top of his inventory... but, In my case it's not there! ...I suppose that it's only available in a specific day, but I dunno when :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this great [GameZone article](http://www.gamezone.com/news/how-to-unlock-lord-shaxx-s-weekly-crucible-bounties-in-destiny-3425703), you need to accomplish 8 steps in order to unlock the crucible weekly bounties :

> ## 1 – Crucible Forged
>
> Defeat Guardians in a Control match with your team holding at least 2 Control zones – *8 kills*.
>
> ## 2 – Crucible Combat
>
> Complete the following things in the game:
>
> **No Guns Barred** – Defeat opposing Guardians in the Clash playlist – *12 kills*.
>
> **Not My Runner** – Defeat opposing Guardians while your team has an active Runner in the Rift playlist – *5 kills*.
>
> **Free For All** – Defeat opposing Guardians in the Rumble playlist – *12 kills*.
>
> **Small-Team Tactics** – Defeat opposing Guardians in the Skirmish playlist – *8 kills*.
>
> **Spelunking with Guns** – Capture Relics in the Salvage playlist – *secure 3 relics*.
>
> ## 3 – Conquer the Day
>
> Complete the following daily challenges :
>
> **Participation Point** – Complete a match in the Daily Crucible playlist
>
> **Spoils to the Victor** – Win a match in the Crucible Daily playlist
>
> **Making a Statement** – Win multiple matches in the Crucible Daily playlist – *a total of 4 wins*
>
> ## 4 – Factions
>
> This requires you to:
>
> *Note: You do not need to actually pledge to each of these factions for the wins. You simply need to talk to the faction leaders and they will give you the quest.*
>
> **Meet with Dead Orbit** – Visit the representative of Dead Orbit, Arach Jalaal, in the Tower Hangar
>
> **This is Dead Orbit Territory** – Win matches in the Control playlist for Dead Orbit – *a total of 2 wins*
>
> **Dead Orbit Rifter** – Win matches in the Rift playlist – *a total of 2 wins*
>
> **Return to Arach Jalaal** – Return to Arach Jalaal in the Tower Hangar
>
> **The Future War Cult** – Visit the representative of Future War Cult, Lakshmi-2, in the Tower Hangar
>
> **Clash for the Future** – Win matches in the Clash playlist for the Future War Cult – *a total of 2 wins*
>
> **Future Rumble Cult** – Finish as one of the top three competitors in the Rumble playlist – *a total of 2 top 3 placements*
>
> **Return to Lakshmi-2** – Return to Lakshmi-2 in the Tower Hangar
>
> **Meet with New Monarchy** – Visit the representative of New Monarchy, Executor Hideo, at Tower North
>
> **New Monarchy Skimisher** – Win matches in the Skirmish playlist for New Monarchy – *a total of 2 wins*
>
> **New Monarchy Relic Seeker** – Win matches in the Salvage playlist for New Monarchy – *a total of 2 wins*
>
> **Return to Executor Hideo** – Return to Executor Hideo in Tower North
>
> ## 5 – Trials Practice
>
> Win a total of 5 matches in Elimination playlist.
>
> ## 6 – Break the Ceiling from Arcite 99-40
>
> Win 5 crucible matches with a score of at least 1,200.
>
> ## 7 – Weapon Master from Banshee-44
>
> Complete the following:
>
> **More Bullets** – Win multiple matches in the Crucible with at least six Auto Rifle kills – *a total of 3 wins*
>
> **Burst of Bullets** – Win multiple matches in the Crucible with at least six Pulse Rifle kills – *a total of 3 wins*
>
> **Nimble Bullets** – Win multiple matches in the Crucible with at least six Scout Rifle kills – *a total of 3 wins*
>
> **Point and Shoot** – Win multiple matches in the Crucible with at least six Hand Cannon kills – *a total of 3 wins*
>
> ## 8 – The Mountaintop
>
> You need to earn a total of 9 points. Winning a Crucible match nets you 3 points; however, starting a new match costs 1 point.
>
> ---

When you complete The Mountaintop quest, you'll be rewarded with the Legendary Rocket Launcher, '**The Hothead**'. **You'll also be eligible for Lord Shaxx's weekly Crucible bounties, which refresh every week.**